# Difference between PRIVATE and PUBLIC field?

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

I noticed that with this code:

```
public List<foo> FooList = new() { foo1, foo2, foo3 };
private List<foo> _fooList = new() { foo1, foo2, foo3 };
```

when the app runs, FooList has all three objects but _fooList has three nulls [null, null, null].
Why is this initialization occurring like this?

[image: private field]

[image: public field]

I tried to use a debugger.

Comment: The access modifier shouldn’t have any impact on that

Comment: its LINQ problem?)

Comment: Probably your private list is initialized when the Instance used are still null

Comment: No, the calling function Greet() is already called after all instances have been initialized.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What happens if you fill the `private` list in `Awake()` or `Start()`? Does it still contain null entries? Please note that initializing variables inline when dependencies are concerned is not done in a guaranteed order, which I assume is why Steve assumed they are not initialized at the time of variable init. Maybe show us the `Instance` code for each of the classes. As Daniel said, the access modifier should not influence execution.